# Handle cloudant db connection failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudant

I am working on back end node application where we are making calls to Cloudant db using the "nodejs-cloudant" module. I faced intermittent issues wherein the db went down and it disrupted the flow of the process.

So that left me wondering if there is a way to handle connection failures and attempt fixed number of retries before failing totally.

When researching i came across the "retry" plugin. But pondering more into it, it handles only scenarios where we get HTTP 429 error code which corresponds to maximum number of attempts.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if desired you could copy the `retry` plugin and modify the logic for your needs: https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant/blob/master/plugins/retry.js#L65

more info:
https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#the-retry-plugin
https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#request-plugins

Comment: Thanks, that's a smart way..Let me check it out..Is there an efficient way to test the above behavior??

Comment: I am just curious..Isnt it supposed to be a straightforward feature? I see this among other noSQL db's straight out of the box..